# Unity3D C# - Cannot implicitly convert type `string' to `int'

Tags: c#, string, list

I am converting my .js list to c#. This is what I have:

```
List<string> allflipping = new List<string>["020-030-031","032-033-023","013-003-002","001-000-010"];
```

And I get this error:

```
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `string' to `int'
```

I googled and cannot find answer that can make it work. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use different brackets

```
List<string> allflipping = 
       new List<string>{"020-030-031","032-033-023","013-003-002","001-000-010"};
```

in c# you need to use `{` instead of `[`  to initialize list with values

EDIT:

to use array you need to create it like this:

```
var arrayOfStrings = 
         new string[] {"020-030-031","032-033-023","013-003-002","001-000-010"};
```

Comment: I actually want just array of strings. So by using {} I will get the array of string? Man, c#'s array is rather confusing.

Comment: @sooon to create array use my example from edit. First example is creating list not array

Comment: is it a var?? or string?

Comment: @sooon `var` is just a shortcut, compiler will replace it with `string[]`

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use `{}` insted `[]`

```
List<string> allflipping = new List<string>
{
   "020-030-031",
   "032-033-023",
   "013-003-002",
   "001-000-010"
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you've put that in square brackets. It's as if you're trying to create an array of `List<string>`, using your strings as the size of the array.

I suspect you meant to use a [*collection initializer*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) with curly braces:

```
List<string> allflipping = new List<string> {
    "020-030-031", "032-033-023", "013-003-002", "001-000-010"
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is right. But just your should have used `{}` insted `[]`.

**Try it :**

```
List<string> allflipping = 
       new List<string>{"020-030-031","032-033-023","013-003-002","001-000-010"};
```

refer This link for [Object and Collection Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)

**Edit :**

You can also omit the new operator if an initializer is provided, like this:
You can initialize string array as below manner.

```
string[] allflipping = { "020-030-031", "032-033-023", "013-003-002", "001-000-010" };
```

**OR :**

```
string[] allflipping = new string[] { "020-030-031", "032-033-023", "013-003-002", "001-000-010" };
```

For more information refer this link.

[Arrays Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

**OR :**

[Single-Dimensional Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0a7fscd0.aspx)

I hope it will help you.